# How do I write a MySQL query to obtain a nested JSON array using JOINS?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I'm working on a planning like project, where I have to load all information from the mysqli database in a specific JSON format. (Otherwise they cannot change it)

So the format should be the same like this:

```
{  
   "data":[  
      {  
         "id_profile":"66",
         "nom":"BARRAUD ",
         "groupe":"1",
         "tasks":[  
            {  
               "id_counter":"8",
               "id_profile":"66",
               "from_interval":"1528092000",
               "to_interval":"1528138800",
               "counter":"16",
               "hrname":"EC2"
            },
            {  
               "id_counter":"458",
               "id_profile":"66",
               "from_interval":"1532412000",
               "to_interval":"1532458800",
               "counter":"16",
               "hrname":"EC1"
            },
            {  
               "id_counter":"466",
               "id_profile":"66",
               "from_interval":"1532757600",
               "to_interval":"1532804400",
               "counter":"14",
               "hrname":"EC1"
            }
         ]
      }
]}
```

Here's the original code that they use:

```php
<?php

if (isset($_GET['counter'])) {
    require_once '../functions.php';

    $sDateHour = $_GET['sDateHour'];
    $eDateHour = $_GET['eDateHour'];

    $now = time() - 24 * 60 * 60;
    $fn = new Func();
    $fn->select('id_profile, nom, groupe', 'profile', '', " date_f_contract>='$now' AND groupe>0 ORDER BY nom");

    $sel = new Func();
    $getHrName = new Func();

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fn->select)) {
        $pr_id = $row['id_profile'];

        $sel->select('*', 'counter', '', " from_interval>='$sDateHour' AND to_interval<='$eDateHour' AND id_profile='$pr_id'");
        $nr = mysqli_num_rows($sel->select);

        if ($nr > 0) {
            //here we have to do the total counter
            $totalCounter = 0;
            $from_interval = 0;
            $to_interval = 0;
            $name = "";

            $tmp_id_profile = 0;
            $tmp_f_int = 0;
            $tmp_to_int = 0;

            while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sel->select)) {
                $frint = $r['from_interval'];
                $toint = $r['to_interval'];

                $counter_ct = $r['counter'];

                $totalCounter += $counter_ct;

                $getHrName->select('libelle AS lbl, COUNT(libelle) AS totalHr', "horraire", "", " date_heure_deb>='$frint' AND date_heure_fin<='$toint' AND id_profile='$pr_id' GROUP BY libelle ORDER BY totalHr DESC LIMIT 1");
                $rr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getHrName->select);
                $r['hrname'] = $rr['lbl'];
                $name = $rr['lbl'];

                $r['counter'] = $rr['totalHr'];

                $row['tasks'][] = $r;
            }
        }
        $res[] = $row;
    }

    $temp['data'] = $res;
    $fn->deconnect();
    $sel->deconnect();

    echo json_encode($temp, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
}
```

But this is way too long to load datas and I was thinking about an opportunity using Joins? Would that be possible in this situation to use any of the JOINS? Would that give me a faster result?

I've been trying to change the query into:

```
SELECT pr.id_profile, pr.nom, pr.groupe, ct.* FROM profile AS pr 
INNER JOIN counter AS ct ON pr.id_profile = ct.id_profile WHERE
(ct.from_interval>='$sDateHour' AND ct.to_interval<='$eDateHour') AND
pr.date_f_contract>='$now' AND groupe>0 ORDER BY nom
```

Comment: Yup.  That would probably be faster than doing a join in php on a row by row basis which seems to be what's happening in the pasted code.  Are you stuck on something in particular?  Getting an error? or not getting the results you want?

Comment: "Would that be possible in this situation to use any of the JOINS?" Yes it looks like it "Would that give me a faster result?" If the columns used in the ON clause are NOT indexed the JOIN might be running slower.. Non indexed joins on two tables run as a two nested for loops.. You should provide the `SHOW CREATE TABLE table` for every table involved

Comment: @Jody  I'm stuck in transforming the repeated data using INNER JOIN into a nested array, such as tasks[] in this case..  I find it impossible to do

Answer (score 0):

In general, yes. Joins are always better than separate queries and much easier to read.
Next time please post the code in a better format. It is really hard to read that thing as of now.
If I read it correct, this should work, even when you should **really** switch from mysqli to PDO:

```
SELECT
            `profile`.id_profile,
            `profile`.nom,
            `profile`.groupe,

            counter.from_interval,
            counter.to_interval,
            counter.counter,

            libelle AS lbl,
            COUNT(libelle) AS totalHr
FROM        `profile`
INNER JOIN  counter
    ON      counter.id_profile = `profile`.id_profile
INNER JOIN  horraire
    ON      horraire.id_profile = `profile`.id_profile
            AND horraire.date_heure_deb >= counter.from_interval
            AND horraire.date_heure_fin <= counter.to_interval
WHERE       `profile`.date_f_contract >= CURDATE() AND `profile`.groupe > 0
            AND from_interval >= '$sDateHour' AND to_interval <= '$eDateHour'
GROUP BY    libelle
ORDER BY    totalHr DESC;
```

Then you can do the rest in PHP or (if you are using MySQL +5.7 or MariaDB 10.3) you can use JSON-functions of the database itself.